# VBA Inputbox to Prevent Decimals

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a tool that will help standardize a description catalog of products. I want to have an input box prompt a user to enter a size. I want to encourage size entries like "5-1/2" and prevent users from entering "5.5". Ideally, if the size was entered with a decimal and not a dash with a fraction, I want a message box to pop up saying they can not do that. It would then need to re-show the input box.

Here is what I have -

```
Private Sub CS_Other_Click()
Unload Me
Sheets("Fill In").Activate
Worksheets("Fill In").Range("C2").NumberFormat = "@"
Dim other_casing_size As Variant
other_casing_size = InputBox("Fill in the casing size. Syntax MUST be in the form of X-X/X", "New Casing Size")
Range("C2") = other_casing_size
```

I just dont know the code to prevent an entry with decimals. Even better, if i knew how to code an exact syntax to include or exclude anything I wanted that would be perfect.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-format-a-number-in-an-Excel-sheet-cell-with-architectural-units

Comment: Consider making a `UserForm` instead, you'll have much better and fine-tuned control over what the user can and cannot enter in a `TextBox` control (via e.g. a `KeyDown` handler) than in an `InputBox` - and you get to validate the input before it's submitted, so invalid input can make the OK button disabled and an explanatory validation error message visible.

Comment: If you use `Application.InputBox` with a type of 2, your output will be a string.  You can then use a Regular Expression to test that you have the desired format.  Or you could merely convert a decimal input into a fraction, and remove that restriction as to entry type.

Comment: One more thing: whenever `InputBox` or `Application.InputBox` is used, the fact that the box can be cancelled is always systematically ignored, until it becomes a problem (typically involves a *type mismatch* error). The function returns a `Variant` that will be a `Boolean` if cancelled, and you need to account for that; you can use `VarType` to get the subtype of a `Variant`; if that's `vbBoolean`, box was cancelled and the function's return value shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

A while loop, which checks the input string for a dot or comma would work quite ok, I guess:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputString As String
    Dim inputNumeric As Boolean

    inputString = InputBox("Please, enter a number!")
    inputNumeric = isNumeric(Evaluate(inputString))

    Do While InStr(1, inputString, ".") Or _
            InStr(1, inputString, ",") Or _
            Not inputNumeric

        If Not CBool(inputNumeric) Then
            MsgBox "You tried to cancel or entered empty value!"
            Exit Do
        End If

        MsgBox "Please, do not write dot or comma!"

        inputString = InputBox("Please, enter a number!")
        inputNumeric = isNumeric(Evaluate(inputString))
    Loop

End Sub
```

The `isNumeric()` checks the input for being able to be converted to numeric. Thus `5-1/2` should be ok.

Concerning cancellation or entering empty value from the `InputBox()` - it really depends on the business logic of the "app", but in the case above - there is a msgbox and it exits the loop.

Comment: And handle cancellation by jumping out of the loop with `Exit Do` ...but you can't do that with the deprecated `While...Wend` loop block; use `Do While...Loop` instead.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Thanks, Mathieu. Cancellation and empty value are rather separate concerns, but I guess these could be handled with `Exit Do` quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Write a separate function responsible for that prompt, and use it e.g. like this:

```
Dim casingSize As String
If GetCasingSize(casingSize) Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = casingSize
End If
```

The function needs to return a `Boolean` for this to work - it returns `True` if the input is valid, `False` if there's no valid input to work with (e.g. prompt was cancelled). What makes this work, is passing the result as a `ByRef` argument, like this:

```
Public Function GetCasingSize(ByRef outResult As String) As Boolean
    Do            
        Dim raw As Variant
        raw = InputBox("Casing size?")
        If VarType(raw) = vbBoolean Then
            'handle cancelled prompt:
            Exit Do
        End If

        If ValidateFractional(raw) Then
            'handle valid input:
            outResult = CStr(raw)
            GetCasingSize = True
            Exit Do
        End If

        'handle invalid input:
        If MsgBox("The value '" & raw & "' is not valid. Try again?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

Note the `ValidateFractional` function is its own concern - a separate, `Private` function would work, but I'd recommend making it `Public`, and [unit-testing it](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/Unit-Testing) to make sure it works as intended given a wide variety of edge-case inputs - and having it in a separate function means the logic in `GetCasingSize` doesn't need to change if the validation needs to be fine-tuned; for example this naive implementation uses the `Like` operator and would work for `5-1/4`, but not for e.g. `15-5/8`:

```
Public Function ValidateFractional(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    ValidateFractional = value Like "#[-]#/#"
End Function
```

Using *Regular Expressions* for this would probably be a good idea.